# Multi-Domain, Multi-Client reCAPTCHA use

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have a system which creates a website automatically for the client. I would like to implement reCAPTCHA in this system, but I need an API key to implement it. As I have many clients, and clients have access to the file system, I cannot use a single public/private key for all customers. Can I create an API key programmatically for each client, or is there another solution? If using reCAPTCHA is impossible, then is there an alternative which meets this requirement?

Comment: There are plenty of CAPTCHAs out there, but what requirement do you need met?  Just the ability to not need an API key?  You could run one yourself.  They often aren't as good, but they will prevent just about all of the run-of-the-mill spam bots from posting stuff in your forms.

Comment: There can't be an API key, or I can get one programmatically. The solution has to be difficult to defeat, without me wasting too much time on it. I don't want to role my own CAPTCHA solution, just like you shouldn't try and do your own cryptography. I can use an alternative, but I'd like it to be a good one which is known to stop bots.

Comment: I'm not suggesting writing your own CAPTCHA... I'm suggesting using one off the shelf and hosting it yourself so that you don't have to worry about API keys.  I've used Securimage in the past and haven't had any trouble.  http://www.phpcaptcha.org/  There are many others.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I had the same problem, here your solution: You can now use the Secure token, obtained at: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/secure_token

Cheers Jens

Answer (score 5):

Before July 2014 (or so), it was possible to create a global key for reCAPTCHA through [the reCaptcha admin page](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create), as seen in the screenshot below.

Unfortunately, this option is no longer available. Existing global keys still work, but it's no longer possible to create new global keys. Sorry. :(

[image: "Enable this key on all domains (global key)"]

Comment: That will generate a global public and a global private key. That would be fine normally, but since clients have access to their files, someone could get a website on my service's private key by creating their own website, lifting the key, and using it in an attack against another site on the service. This is assuming that one can successfully break an reCAPTCHA on a site with knowledge of their private key, which I assume is the case, as they instruct that the key remain private.

Comment: Oh, I see. The reCAPTCHA private key is only used to verify solutions, and a solution that's already been verified once will fail if checked again. As far as I'm aware, there's no way to use it to "break" the CAPTCHA; in this situation, it's probably fine.

Comment: I hope that's the case, but I need a more definitive answer to be sure that this is not a security vulnerability, which would enable someone to launch a limitless brute force attack.

Comment: since there is no more global key, to overcome this problem could an iframe containing the recaptcha be used? It would work like this: the callback of the recaptcha would send the response of captcha to the parent page. The validation of that would be done by the parent page when the form is submitted. Are there issues with this that I can't think of?